# The third element wraps to the next line after resizing browser

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I worked on the code i had posted here and fixed it so it  does the things i wanted to but the third element in the row wraps to the next line when the browser is between 992px and 1350px. when the browser is between 992px and 1350px the third element in he row wraps to the next line, i have tried with display: inline-block, the left, rifght, center, floats, the flexbox and many other things but nothing seems to work with the media queries in the csss

CSS

```
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Times, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
}

}
/**** Row (for the responsive design***/

.row {
    padding: 15%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

/**** Header ****/

header {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    padding-top: 2.5%;
    text-align: center;
}

/**** Article styles and position ****/


#art1, #art2, #art3 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 40%;
    width: 31%;

}

#art1 {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 25px; 
}

#art2 {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#art3 {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 10px; 
}

/**** Article titles ****/

#lorem1 {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    left: 70%;
    margin-bottom: -28.9px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
}

#lorem2 {
    background-color: turquoise;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    left: 70%;
    top: 20%;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    margin-bottom: -28.9px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

#lorem3 {
    background-color: crimson;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    left: 70%;
    margin-bottom: -28.9px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
}

/**** Content of the articles ****/
p {
    border: 1px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: hidden;
}

.p1, .p2, .p3 {
    background-color: mediumpurple;
    color: gold;
    padding: 35px 10px 10px 15px;
}

/**** Media queries ****/

/**Mobile devices**/

@media (max-width: 767px) {

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

    #art1, #art2, #art3 {
    width: 94.5%;
    display: block;
}


#art1, #art2, #art3 {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px; 
    }


}

/**Tablets**/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    *{ 
    margin: 0; }

#art1, #art2 {
    width: 45.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    }

#art3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 92%;
    position: relative;
    left: 2.5%;
    }

#art1 {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 25px; 
    }   

#art2 {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

#art3 {
    margin: 10px 40px 10px 20px; 

}

/**Desktop computers**/

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    }

.row {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: flex-start; 
   flex-direction: row;
   border: 2px solid red; /* not necesary just checkiing it'd  appear on the screen*/
}

#art1, #art2, #art3 {
    width: 31%;
    height: 30%;
    }


#art1 {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 25px; 
    }

#art2 {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

#art3 {
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 10px;
    fle 
    }

}

/**** Deskptops above 1360px ****/

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1350px) {

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

.row {
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center ; /* for horizontal aligning of child divs */
   align-items : center ; /* for vertical aligning */
}

#art1, #art2, #art3 {
    width: 31%;
    display: inline-block;
    }


#art1 {
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 25px; 
    }

#art2 {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

#art3 {
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 10px; 
    }


}
```

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles-2.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Week 2 assigment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="row">
        <header>
            <h1>Our Menu</h1>
        </header>

        <article id="art1" >
            <h2 id="lorem1">Chiken</h2>
            <p class="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </article>

        <article id="art2" >
            <h2 id="lorem2">Beef</h2>
            <p class="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </article>

        <article id="art3">
            <h2 id="lorem3">Sushi</h2>
            <p class="p3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </article>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are your H2 elements positioned absolutely? Half of this code makes no sense..

Comment: Yeah this is sloppy, why are you using the bootstrap classes? Did you get this somewhere?

Comment: H2 with relative postion left a blank space in the right side of the page. it was for something that asked using that responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not following any general layout. I suggest checking out w3 and looking at float/clearfix or flexbox layouts so you can figure out stuff before posting too much.

here is a simple vanilla way too display three columns in a line. You can add your media queries to make the sections 100% on resize.

Your CSS is excessive and uses bootstrap classes without having it in your head. And your css plays with these classes. I am not sure what's going on here haha. Hope this helps bro!

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */

section {
  width:31.33%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:1%;
}

<body>
 <header>
    <h1>Our menu</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <section class="1">
      <h2 class="loremab1">lorem 1</h2>
      <p class="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="2">
      <h2 class="loremab2">lorem 2</h2>
      <p class="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="3">
      <h2 class="loremab3">lorem 3</h2>
      <p class="p3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```